# Html create a bot for automatic tasks

Tags: html, google-chrome, task, bots

Hey I'm making a chrome extension in HTML and I want the extensions to do automatic tasks like buying an item automatically for example, kind of like a sniper. But I don't know if it is possible and if it is I don't know how. So it would be nice if someone could explain to me or link a website that explains it well cause I didn't find any. Thank you

Comment: You won't get far with HTML alone as its a markup language and not a programming language. You probably will want to learn some basic JS before writing a full-blown extension to be quite honest.